# EF GroupBy query optimization

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this method:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var orders = await db.Orders.AsNoTracking().GroupBy(x => x.Status).Select(g => new { Status = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.Status, x => x.Count);
        ViewBag.InWork = orders[WebApplication.Models.Order.OrderStatus.InWork];
        ViewBag.InProcess = orders[WebApplication.Models.Order.OrderStatus.InProcess];
        ViewBag.Accepted = orders[WebApplication.Models.Order.OrderStatus.Accepted];
        ViewBag.Deleted = orders[WebApplication.Models.Order.OrderStatus.Deleted];

        return View();
    }
```

and it's generated this SQL:

```
SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [Status], 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[Status] AS [K1], 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[Orders] AS [Extent1]
        GROUP BY [Extent1].[Status]
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

How can I escape from `SELECT FROM SELECT` and optimize this query?

Comment: It looks like the `GroupBy` is causing it... are you having performance issues? Missing index on `Status`?

Comment: No, I haven't performance issues. I thought that this query can be more simpler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with the generated query. EF does generate verbose T-SQL, but that doesn't mean it's inefficient. If the generated query generates a decent execution plan there is no need to try to get EF to generate T-SQL the way you would have written it.

However the code would be easier to read like this:

```
var orders = await db.Orders.AsNoTracking()
                            .GroupBy(x => x.Status)
                            .Select(g => new { Status = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
                            .ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.Status, x => x.Count);
```

Answer (score 4):

Building on MM's answer, you could simplify the query even more by getting rid of the `Select`:

```
var orders = await db.Orders.AsNoTracking()
                     .GroupBy(x => x.Status)
                     .ToDictionaryAsync(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

**UPDATE**

As mentioned in sDima's comment below, this is actually *less* efficient than the original query.

Assuming a simple Consumers table with five fields:

```
Id(Int), 
DisplayName(NVarchar(128))
ImageUrl(NVarchar(128))
Gender(Int)
SignedUpOn(DateTimeOffset)
```

If we run this query:

```
Consumers.GroupBy(c => c.Gender).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count())
```

it will generate this SQL code:

```
SELECT [t0].[Gender] AS [Key]
FROM [Consumers] AS [t0]
GROUP BY [t0].[Gender]
GO

DECLARE @x1 Int = 1
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[DisplayName], [t0].[ImageUrl], [t0].[Gender], [t0].[SignedUpOn]
FROM [Consumers] AS [t0]
WHERE @x1 = [t0].[Gender]
GO

DECLARE @x1 Int = 2
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[DisplayName], [t0].[ImageUrl], [t0].[Gender], [t0].[SignedUpOn]
FROM [Consumers] AS [t0]
WHERE @x1 = [t0].[Gender]
```

which is quite yucky. But the original query form:

```
Consumers.GroupBy(c => c.Gender)
         .Select(g => new { Key = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
         .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count)
```

will generate this SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Count], [t0].[Gender] AS [Key]
FROM [Consumers] AS [t0]
GROUP BY [t0].[Gender]
```

which is pretty close to what you would write by hand.

Comment: This is not effective, because SQL Server gets all columns of table.

Comment: You're right - I have updated the answer to illustrate.